# Treewalker Exception, Eclipse

Tags: xml, eclipse, exception, tomcat, jboss

I worked on a project using eXistdb. XML Java API, etc. After that anytime I try to create dynamic web prj in eclipse I get this error. When I want to create a new server instance I get this. Please help!!! Or I should completely change my path to a C# programmer using Visual Studio because I am facing this error for a long time. I installed new eclipse, tomcat server it didn't go away!

"The selected wizard could not be started.
Plug-in "org.eclipse.jst.servlet.ui" was unable to instantiate class "org.eclipse.jst.servlet.ui.project.facet.WebProjectWizard".
org/apache/xml/serializer/TreeWalker"

Thanks in advanced.

NOTE: It is not tomcat's problem, I installed new eclipse, created new workspace, installed new JRE, stil I am able to create a java project, but when I create a class it gives me

An internal error occurred during: "Task List Save Job".
org/apache/xml/serializer/TreeWalker

The second error is :
Could not save master table to file 'C:\Users\SaraS\Desktop\solve.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources.safetable\org.eclipse.core.resources'.
C:\Users\SaraS\Desktop\solve.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources.safetable\org.eclipse.core.resources (The system cannot find the path specified)

Plz note that solve is my workspace name. Help!

Update: I installed new JRE, so now I am able to create a dynamic web project then create a class. But when I want to run the tomcat server I again get the first mentioned error!

Comment: Note: I ran tomcat through command line and it is working properly. So only the problem exists within Eclipse!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I resolved the issue. There was a problem with xiling package( If I am right with the name) in JRE. Installed new JRE and it works fine now. Thanks.